# UIActivityViewController share shows different options with different schemes in same app

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am having a weird issue with UIActivityViewController share functionality. I have 3 flavors of the same app as Development, QA, Production with 1 codebase. (There is absolutely no if checks or anything the same code always). The same line of code for sharing functionality is behaving differently between flavors and i just cannot figure out why.

The code to get share activity.

```swift
let shareText = "Hey, check this out!"
let shareURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, shareURL], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes  = [
   .assignToContact,
   .markupAsPDF,
   .openInIBooks,
   .postToFlickr,
   .postToFacebook,
   .postToFlickr,
   .postToVimeo,
   .print,
   .saveToCameraRoll,
   .postToWeibo,
   .postToTwitter,
   .addToReadingList
]

return activityViewController
```

The code to show it:

```swift
let shareHelper = ShareHelper()
let shareActivityViewController = shareHelper.getShareActivity()

present(shareActivityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In development scheme it shows:
[image: Message is there]

In production, much less options
[image: Message is not there and others]

Comment: Did you try create new application and run the same code? This can tell us if there is something wrong with configuration of your application or something wrong with `UIActivityViewController` itself.

Comment: I am quite sure it has something to do with my configuration but cannot figure out what could that be? Cause all these schemes i duplicated over the original one. Thanks a lot for the idea